# background image is not changing using jquery on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dears am trying to change div background-image using jquery on click as shown in code below its working on all browsers except IE.....help please

```
<div id="section1" class="section111">
        <div class="container">
            <div style="width: 100%; z-index: 999999999;" class="ServicesTitle">
                <p class="Main_TitaleServices">SERVICES & SOLUTIONS</p>
                <p class="slogan">Full Solutions for a Perfect Business   </p>
            </div>
            <div id="title-underline" style="margin-bottom: -30px;">
                <img src="../../App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/title-underline.png">
            </div>
            <div class="firstrow">
                <div class="col-lg-3 divServices ">
                </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the script

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#WebsiteDevelopment").click(function () {
    $("#section1").css("background-image", "url(/App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/webdevelopment.jpg !important")
    /

});
$("#btnWebsiteDevelopment").click(function () {


    $("#section1").css("background-image", "url(/App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/section1bg.png")

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamically switching 'background-image' doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205110/dynamically-switching-background-image-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set background image in html that work in Internet explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449185/how-to-set-background-image-in-html-that-work-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Did you try to remove the !important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `background` instead of `background-image`.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#WebsiteDevelopment").click(function () {
    $("#section1").css("background", "url(/App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/webdevelopment.jpg !important")
    /

});
$("#btnWebsiteDevelopment").click(function () {


    $("#section1").css("background", "url(/App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/section1bg.png")

});
});
</script>
```

Or use pure javascript approach,

```
document.getElementById('section1').backgroundImage = "url('url(/App_Themes/ThemeEn/Images/webdevelopment.jpg !important')";
```

Comment: Dear AKA, I tried using background but stil not working

Comment: I have updated the answer. Use the second one with javascript fix.

Comment: Glad to help you.